# AseBulkCopy not available in list of commands

Tags: c#, sybase, sqlbulkcopy, sybase-asa

I am trying to bulk insert records in Sybase using C#. I have included **Sybase.Data.AseClient.dll** in my solution and able to create connection.

But problem is there is no **AseBulkCopy** command available as shown in screenshot below. What could be the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by using **Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient.dll**